# React Native has an error when use auth()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I got some error when I trying to login with Firebase SDK.
What should I do with my code ?

my Firebase version is ^5.7.3

```
// LoginFform.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../config/firebase';
import {Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner} from "./common/Common";

class LoginForm extends Component {
state = {email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false};
 onButtonPress() {
     const {email, password} = this.state;
     this.setState({error: '', loading: true});
     console.log(email);
     console.log(password);
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
         .then(()=>{
             this.onLoginSuccess();
         })
         .catch((err) => {
             firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .then(()=>{
                     this.onLoginSuccess();
                 })
                 .catch((err) => {
                     this.onLoginFalied(err);
                 })
         })
  }
}



// firebase.js
import firebase from '@firebase/app'

firebase.initializeApp({
  /* My config */
});
export default firebase;
```

this is an error message >> _firebase.default.auth is not a function

But when i change import firebase from '@firebase/app' to import firebase from 'firebase' in firebase.js I got different error >> Invariant Violation:Objects are not valid as a React Child

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `react-native-firebase`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use import firebase from '@firebase/app'; and then add import '@firebase/auth'